# How this code can be done in an improved manner

Tags: php, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I want to replace switch statements here with proper code. I need suggestion of doing this in an improved manner.

```
switch(true) {
    case ($value === 'test1'):
    $testArray['class'] = 'incomplete';
    return $this->icon(
        'test_0.png',
        $testArray
    );
    case ($value === 'test2'):
    $testArray['class'] = 'progress';
    return $this->icon(
        'test_1.png',
        $testArray
    );
    case ($value === 'test3'):
    $testArray['class'] = 'complete';
    return $this->icon(
        'test_3.png',
        $testArray
    );
}
```

Comment: Use if , else if and else

Comment: Why on earth would you do this instead of `switch($value) { case 'test1': ...`

Comment: Looks like a better fit for : http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

try to set `$value` with `'incomplete'`, `'progress'` or`'complete'`. rename the imgs to `incomplete.png`, `progress.png` and `complete.png`

Then do this:

```
$testArray['class'] = $value; 
return $this->icon(
    $value.'.png',
    $testArray
);
```

It all depents on the way you set `$value`. But if you mange to set the up the right way it's shorter and easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

improved switch statement is,

```
    switch($value) {
    case 'test1':
        $testArray['class'] = 'incomplete';
        $image = 'test_0.png';
        break;
    case 'test2':
        $testArray['class'] = 'progress';
        $image = 'test_1.png';
        break;
    case 'test3':
        $testArray['class'] = 'complete';
        $image = 'test_3.png';
        break;
    default :
        break;
}
return $this->icon($image,$testArray);
```

or use if statment,

```
if ($value == 'test1') {
    $testArray['class'] = 'incomplete';
    $image = 'test_0.png';
} elseif ($value == 'test2') {
    $testArray['class'] = 'progress';
    $image = 'test_1.png';
} else {
    $testArray['class'] = 'complete';
    $image = 'test_3.png';
}

return $this->icon($image,$testArray);
```